# Cannot possibly work without effective root in forked process

Tags: linux, rust, terminal, terminal-emulator

relatively naive question here - I always program for *nix through Mac but am not familiar with Linux.

I'm writing a terminal emulator in Rust. It forks itself and, in the child process, becomes `/usr/bin/login` via `execle`. This works perfectly in macOS. The implementation is [here](https://github.com/adamsoutar/velocity/blob/master/velocity-core/src/shell_layer/mac_os.rs#L102).

On Linux however, `login` prints "Cannot possibly work without effective root". I don't really know what this means. I can run my terminal emulator with `sudo`, but then the logged-in user is root, which I don't want. I want to start it as a normal user, and avoid this "effective root" error.

In an attempt to toubleshoot, I put a line of `seteuid(0.into()).unwrap()` in my program before `execle`, but that hangs the entirety of Pop!_OS on my machine and then prints

```
[xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
velocity-sfml: ../../src/xcb_io.c:278: poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.
zsh: IOT instruction (core dumped)  ./velocity-sfml
```

Do anyone know how I can give my program an "effective root" on Linux without launching it as root?

Comment: On MacOS, `login` is setuid. On Linux, it's not setuid -- the expectation is that it's run from a root process like `sshd` or `systemd`. So you can't start a new login yourself on Linux, it can only be done from a system process.

Comment: You should be able to use `sudo login`

Comment: Thanks for the info! I changed my code so that it spawns `sudo login -f adam` (my username), and it works, but the terminal starts with `[sudo] password for adam:`, which other terminal emulators on Linux don't do when they start. Have I understood correctly? If not, what is the usual way that Linux terminal emulators spawn the shell program and set up PATH etc.?

Comment: Right. Sure. But xterm doesn't need that - it just pops open the shell with the environment configured

Comment: xterm doesn't create a new login, it runs with the same userid.

Comment: `login` is for logging in as a different user. Is that what you really need to do?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I've just misunderstood and I actually don't need to use `login`. How does something like xterm set up the environment? If I make my program just spawn `/usr/bin/zsh` directly, things like `$PATH` aren't set up.

Comment: Use the `-l` option to specify that it should be a login shell.

Comment: Thanks! That sounds closer to what I'm looking for. Unfortunately, `/usr/bin/zsh -l` doesn't set up the env, like `$PATH`. Whereas that was set when I did `sudo login -f`

Comment: It should load the same `.zprofile`, `.zshrc`, and `.zlogin` as it does when you login normally.

Comment: Hmm. I've uploaded a [screenshot](https://i.snipboard.io/UvswGz.jpg) where the left is `sudo login -f adam` and the right is `/usr/bin/zsh -l`. They're set up very different. Maybe this is becoming more of a Super User question than a Stack Overflow question. Thanks so much for your help so far!

Comment: @deeBo could you compare these two inputs with what happens when you just type `env` in your usual terminal?